# Select count from multiple tables and group by one field

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by

I have "users" table with fields
user_name, user_id

I have data tables like

```
data_table_2012_10
data_table_2012_11
data_table_2012_12
data_table_2013_01
data_table_2013_02
```

each table contains the following fields

```
user_id, type ('ALARM', 'EMERGENCY', 'ALIVE', 'DEAD'), date_time
```

There will be millions of records in each table.

I have to select the count of type from the data_tables within the time frame given by the user, as well as have to get the corresponding name of the user with the help of user_id.

Can some one help me out with the best solution.

Comment: are you creating table for every month of the year? this is bad schema design because you can't hardly know where table to join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query where DATE1 and DATE2 is your date range. You should union all tables in the inner query. Also you can try to make a query dynamically to include in the inner query only those tables that are in a date range you use:

```
select t.user_id,t.type, MAX(users.user_name), SUM(t.cnt)
from
(
select user_id,type,count(*) cnt
from data_table_2012_10 where date_time between DATE1 and DATE2
group by user_id,type

union all

select user_id,type,count(*) cnt
from data_table_2012_11 where date_time between DATE1 and DATE2
group by user_id,type

union all
.........................................

union all
select user_id,type,count(*) cnt
from data_table_2013_02 where date_time between DATE1 and DATE2
group by user_id,type
) t
left join users on (t.user_id=users.user_id)
group by t.user_id,t.type
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember not to use UNION, but UNION ALL as UNION will return only merge similar rows into one and that may cause problem